# How to view all TCP connections for your website in Chrome? Is it possible using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, tcp, connection, google-chrome-devtools

I am designing a web application that sends a XMLHttpRequest from javascript to a php file. This is a bottleneck in the website and is interfering quite a bit with the UX, often taking up to a minute for the XMLHttpRequest to load fully. This problem occurs in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Having done some research online I've found that unlike Firefox, Chrome can only have 6 TCP connections at once, which seems to cause the delay in Chrome as it usually has to wait for a socket.

How can I view all the TCP connections and is this possible using Chrome DevTools?

Answer (score 1):

All your XMLHttpRequests will be presented in Chrome DevTools on tab "Network". You can specify only XHR requests for more comfortable viewing.